# IMO shortlist problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry

In triangle $ABC$, $M$ is an interior point. Segments $AD$, $BE$ and $CF$ are drawn passing through $M$ such that $D$ lies on $BC$, $E$ lies on $AC$,  and $F$ lies on $AB$.  Prove that

(area of triangle $DEF$)$\le\frac{1}{4} $(area of triangle $ABC$)

I have tried using Ceva's and Menelaus theorem but ended up in so many equations. The coordinate geometry also didn't yield much success. I also would like to know if there can be any use of projective geometry

Comment: If it's an older problem (which I assume is true since it's quite simple), there are usually solutions alongside the shortlists

Comment: I don't actually know of which year this problem is.  I was just told that it is an IMO shortlisted problem. So it would be difficult to search for so much of papers to see from which year this question is.

Comment: Are you sure you don't the reverse inequality?

Comment: Show that equality is only possible when M is the centroid

Comment: That I am totally aware of but the inequality part is the one which I really want to know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it's really messy but here's what you can do. Denote:
$$AF=x$$ $$BD=z$$ $$CE=y $$

Intuition: We want to get rid of one of $x,y,z$ by using Ceva's Theorem and due to symmetry, we want them to alternate (this will ease the calculations)

What you want to show is that

$$\frac{(b-y)x}{bc}+\frac{z(c-x)}{ac}+\frac{y(a-z)}{ab} \geq \frac{3}{4}$$
by summing the areas of the other $3$ triangles.

If you denote the following:

$$\frac{x}{c}=m$$$$ \frac{y}{b}=n$$$$\frac{z}{a}=p $$

You can the formulate Ceva's Theorem and the claim you want to prove as:

$$mnp=(1-m)(1-n)(1-p)$$

$$Claim: m+n+p-mn-np-mp\geq \frac{3}{4}$$

by just substituting.

Hence, we'd like to show that

$$mnp\leq \frac{1}{8}$$
holds (using the claim and Ceva's Thm we get this)

Now you can get $p$ in terms of $m,n$ from Ceva's Theorem and plug it in
$$mnp\leq \frac{1}{8}$$
to get 
a quadratic in say $m$.

This quadratic will attain its maximum at $\frac{1}{2}$ and you will be done
(if that problem is true and your calculations are OK, that is :D, didn't finish the calculations)